# It's OK to only have SMTP for server-to-server communication?

Tags: email, email-server, spam

I'm configuring an antispam appliance to filter mail traffic coming to our Exchange server. The flow will be something like this:

`(internet)<====>(antispam)<====>(exchange)<====>(users)`

The antispam appliance will be listed in the MX record for my domain, so the mail will be delivered to him.

Users **will not** be sending emails directly using the appliance; they will keep sending using the Exchange server.

Now, the appliance only has port 25 listening on the public network; is this OK for server-to-server communication? Or do I need to enable TLS on the public interface also, so other server can deliver mail to my antispam using a secure connection?

Comment: That depends on whether or not the antispam appliance supports TLS. If it does, I would strongly suggest using it, so that traffic between those servers is encrypted. Otherwise, a "man in the middle" could easily read all the e-mails and I don't think you (or your employer) would want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's OK and enough to have only port 25 open on the relaying/forwarding mail server. A secure connection with TLS is also possible if configured properly to work with port 25. So, you don't need to have another port for that.
See the [rfc3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207).

If you want to have a seperate secure submission port then you need tcp port 587 to be open for that, but which is not your case.

You can see if a server supports TLS by doing a simple telnet and see if it contains the line STARTTLS:
The following dialog from rfc3207 illustrates how a client and server can start a TLS session:

```
   S: <waits for connection on TCP port 25>
   C: <opens connection>
   S: 220 mail.imc.org SMTP service ready
   C: EHLO mail.example.com
   S: 250-mail.imc.org offers a warm hug of welcome
   S: 250-8BITMIME
   S: 250-STARTTLS
   S: 250 DSN
   C: STARTTLS
   S: 220 Go ahead
   C: <starts TLS negotiation>
   C & S: <negotiate a TLS session>
   C & S: <check result of negotiation>
   C: EHLO mail.example.com
   S: 250-mail.imc.org touches your hand gently for a moment
   S: 250-8BITMIME
   S: 250 DSN
```

This is a very nice article on the smtp port mystry: [25, 465, 587... What port should I use?](http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/)

Comment: @Matteo, glad that it helped.